# cant subscribe to a ble service with react native ble-plx

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

new here. I am trying to write an app which pulls data from an ESP32 ble device. I am using the ble-plx library. I have downloaded the SensorTag app https://github.com/PolideaPlayground/SensorTag and have tried to modify it using the following issue: https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx/issues/471

I want to subscribe to a service and update the redux store value when I get a notify callback from the BLE manager. I am familiar with android app development but am new to react. Any guidance is appreciated!
right now I am just trying to log the new characteristic value to the console.
the code that I think should be doing the job is below: (in Saga.js)

```
function* handleConnection(manager: BleManager): Generator<*, *, *> {
var testTask = null;
                           const [error, characteristic]: [?BleError, ?Characteristic] = yield take(setupNotificationChannel)                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
          if (error != null) {                                                                                                                                                                                   
            console.warn("Device name = " + device.localName + "  Device ID = " + device.id)                                                                                                                     
            console.warn(error.message)                                                                                                                                                                          
          }                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
          if (characteristic != null) {                                                                                                                                                                          
            var new_Button_state = yield select(selectors.getButtonState)                                                                                                                                        
            new_Button_state.button_value = characteristic.value                                                                                                                                                 
            yield put(log(characteristic.value))                                                                                                                                                                 
          }                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        if (deviceAction.type === 'DISCONNECT') {                                                                                                                                                                
          yield put(log('Disconnected by user...'));                                                                                                                                                             
          yield put(updateConnectionState(ConnectionState.DISCONNECTING));                                                                                                                                       
          yield call([device, device.cancelConnection]);                                                                                                                                                         
          break;                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        if (deviceAction.type === 'EXECUTE_TEST') {                                                                                                                                                              
          if (testTask != null) {                                                                                                                                                                                
            yield cancel(testTask);                                                                                                                                                                              
          }                                                                                                                                                                                                      
          testTask = yield fork(executeTest, device, deviceAction);                                                                                                                                              
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                        
          }                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      } else if (disconnected) {                                                                                                                                                                                 
        yield put(log('Disconnected by device...'));                                                                                                                                                             
        if (disconnected.error != null) {                                                                                                                                                                        
          yield put(logError(disconnected.error));                                                                                                                                                               
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        break;                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  } catch (error) {                                                                                                                                                                                              
    yield put(logError(error));                                                                                                                                                                                  
  } finally {                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    disconnectedChannel.close();                                                                                                                                                                                 
    yield put(testFinished());                                                                                                                                                                                   
    yield put(updateConnectionState(ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED));                                                                                                                                              
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                              
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  for (;;) {
  // Take action
  const {device}: ConnectAction = yield take('CONNECT');

  const disconnectedChannel = yield eventChannel((emit) => {
    const subscription = device.onDisconnected((error) => {
      emit({type: 'DISCONNECTED', error: error});
    });
    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, buffers.expanding(1));
                                                                                                         

  const setupNotificationChannel = yield eventChannel((emit) => {
    const subscription = device.monitorCharacteristicForService("ab0828b1-198e-4351-b779-901fa0e0371e", "0972EF8C-7613-4075-AD52-756F33D4DA91", (error, characteristic) => {
        emit([error, characteristic])
    })
    return () => {
      subscription.remove()
    }
  }, buffers.expanding(1))

  const deviceActionChannel = yield actionChannel([
    'DISCONNECT',
    'EXECUTE_TEST',
  ]);

  try {
    yield put(updateConnectionState(ConnectionState.CONNECTING));
    yield call([device, device.connect]);
    yield put(updateConnectionState(ConnectionState.DISCOVERING));
    yield call([device, device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics]);
    yield put(updateConnectionState(ConnectionState.CONNECTED));

    for (;;) {
      const {deviceAction, disconnected} = yield race({
        deviceAction: take(deviceActionChannel),
        disconnected: take(disconnectedChannel),
      });

      if (deviceAction) {
          if (deviceAction) {
        if (deviceAction.type == "UPDATE_FLOW") {
          yield put(log("Setting up notifications..."))
          const [error, characteristic]: [?BleError, ?Characteristic] = yield take(setupNotificationChannel)                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
          if (error != null) {                                                                                                                                                                                   
            console.warn("Device name = " + device.localName + "  Device ID = " + device.id)                                                                                                                     
            console.warn(error.message)                                                                                                                                                                          
          }                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
          if (characteristic != null) {                                                                                                                                                                          
            var new_Button_state = yield select(selectors.getButtonState)                                                                                                                                        
            new_Button_state.button_value = characteristic.value                                                                                                                                                 
            yield put(log(characteristic.value))                                                                                                                                                                 
          }                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        if (deviceAction.type === 'DISCONNECT') {                                                                                                                                                                
          yield put(log('Disconnected by user...'));                                                                                                                                                             
          yield put(updateConnectionState(ConnectionState.DISCONNECTING));                                                                                                                                       
          yield call([device, device.cancelConnection]);                                                                                                                                                         
          break;                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        if (deviceAction.type === 'EXECUTE_TEST') {                                                                                                                                                              
          if (testTask != null) {                                                                                                                                                                                
            yield cancel(testTask);                                                                                                                                                                              
          }                                                                                                                                                                                                      
          testTask = yield fork(executeTest, device, deviceAction);                                                                                                                                              
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                        
          }                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      } else if (disconnected) {                                                                                                                                                                                 
        yield put(log('Disconnected by device...'));                                                                                                                                                             
        if (disconnected.error != null) {                                                                                                                                                                        
          yield put(logError(disconnected.error));                                                                                                                                                               
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        break;                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  } catch (error) {                                                                                                                                                                                              
    yield put(logError(error));                                                                                                                                                                                  
  } finally {                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    disconnectedChannel.close();                                                                                                                                                                                 
    yield put(testFinished());                                                                                                                                                                                   
    yield put(updateConnectionState(ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED));                                                                                                                                              
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

}

Comment: One more thing, I know that the BLE Device is working properly, I can subscribe to it and see the data being updated with the nrfConnect app